# What about this OpenCL kernel is causing the error CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE

Tags: neural-network, opencl

I'm having a problem implementing a Feed-Forward MultiLayer Perceptron, with back-prop learning in OpenCL in Java, using JOCL. Here is the kernel code for the calculation phase:

```
    #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
    __kernel void Neuron(__global const double *inputPatterns,
                           __global double *weights,
                           __global const int *numInputs,
                           __global const int *activation,
                           __global const double *bias,
                           __global const int *usingBias,
                           __global double *values,
                           __global const int *maxNumFloats,
                           __global const int *patternIndex,
                           __global const int *inputPatternSize,
                           __global const int *indexOffset,
                           __global const int *isInputNeuron,
                           __global const int *inputs)
    {
       int gid = get_global_id(0);
       double sum = 0.0;
       for(int i = 0; i < numInputs[gid+indexOffset[0]]; i++)
       {
           sum += values[inputs[(gid+indexOffset[0]) * maxNumFloats[0] + i]] *
                   weights[(gid+indexOffset[0]) * maxNumFloats[0] + i];
       }
       if(usingBias[gid+indexOffset[0]])
           sum += bias[gid+indexOffset[0]];
       if(isInputNeuron[gid+indexOffset[0]])
           sum += inputPatterns[gid+indexOffset[0]+(patternIndex[0] * inputPatternSize[0])];
       if(activation[gid+indexOffset[0]] == 1)
           sum = 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-sum));
       values[gid + indexOffset[0]] = sum;
    }
```

Basically, I run this kernel for each layer in the network. For the first layer, there are no "inputs", so the loop does not execute. As the first layer is an input node layer however, it does add the relevant value from the input pattern. This executes fine, and I can read back the values at this point.

When I try and run the SECOND layer however (which does have inputs, every node from the first layer), a call to clFinish() returns the error CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE. Sometimes this error is coupled with a driver crash and recovery. I have read around ([here](http://www.sevenforums.com/crashes-debugging/51028-help-me-configure-registry-correctly-solve-tdr-issue.html) for example) that this might be a problem with TDR timeouts, and have made an attempt to raise the limit but unsure if this is making any difference.

I'm going through the calls to clSetKernelArg() to check for anything stupid, but can anyone spot anything obviously off in the code? It would seem that the error is introduced in the second layer due to the inclusion of the for loop... I can clarify any of the parameters if its needed but it seemed a bit overkill for an initial post.

Also, I'm fully aware this code will probably be an affront to competent coders everywhere, but feel free to flame :P

EDIT: Host code:

```
    //Calc
    for(int k = 0; k < GPUTickList.length; k++)
    {
        clFlush(clCommandQueue);
        clFinish(clCommandQueue);
        //If input nodes
        if(k == 0)
            //Set index offset to 0
            GPUMapIndexOffset.asIntBuffer().put(0, 0);
        else
            //Update index offset
            GPUMapIndexOffset.asIntBuffer().put(0,
                GPUMapIndexOffset.asIntBuffer().get(0) + GPUTickList[k-1]);
        //Write index offset to GPU buffer
        ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(clCommandQueue, memObjects[12], CL_TRUE, 0,
                Sizeof.cl_int, Pointer.to(GPUMapIndexOffset.position(0)), 0, null, null);             
        //Set work size (width of layer)
        global_work_size[0] = GPUTickList[k];
        ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(clCommandQueue, kernel_iterate, 1,
            global_work_offset, global_work_size, local_work_size,
            0, null, null);
    }
```

EDIT 2: I've uploaded the full code to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xGNBn4Gp).

Comment: Do you have a portion of your host code to share? I doubt there is a problem with the kernel itself if it runs for the 1st layer of neurons. Also, have you tried clWaitForEvents() instead of clFinish()?

Comment: Sure, added the bit where this kernel is enqueued in a loop, can post more if needed, just say what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Fixed the error by making everything indexed with [0] a straight kernel parameter, rather than a buffer. Clearly the hardware doesn't like lots of stuff accessing one particular element of a buffer at once.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what you have above the loop.. do you use the queue other than in this loop? Below is something you may want to try out.

```
//flush + finish if you need to before the loop, otherwise remove these lines
clFlush(clCommandQueue);
clFinish(clCommandQueue);

cl_event latestEvent;
//Calc
for(int k = 0; k < GPUTickList.length; k++)
{
    //If input nodes
    if(k == 0)
        //Set index offset to 0
        GPUMapIndexOffset.asIntBuffer().put(0, 0);
    else
        //Update index offset
        GPUMapIndexOffset.asIntBuffer().put(0,
            GPUMapIndexOffset.asIntBuffer().get(0) + GPUTickList[k-1]);
    //Write index offset to GPU buffer
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(clCommandQueue, memObjects[12], CL_TRUE, 0,
            Sizeof.cl_int, Pointer.to(GPUMapIndexOffset.position(0)), 0, null, null);             
    //Set work size (width of layer)
    global_work_size[0] = GPUTickList[k];
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(clCommandQueue, kernel_iterate, 1,
        global_work_offset, global_work_size, local_work_size,
        0, null, &latestEvent);
    clWaitForEvents(1, &latestEvent);
}
```

Comment: I did have a go with events, but it caused me trouble so I stuck to blocking calls and clFinish(), I'll give it another go now and see how it fares. Also I've [pastebinned](http://pastebin.com/xGNBn4Gp) the whole file, the GPUTrain function is the important one (it's a bit monolithic). Thanks for the input!

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't realize you are using java+ocl. I hope the pointer stuff still works. I'll take another look at the code when I get a chance.

Comment: The call to clWaitForEvents() immediately following the clEnqueueNDRangeKernel() call breaks on the second pass with CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES. This must be a symptom of the same problem, probably that the kernel is breaking.     PS. Yeah, I did mention that at the top :P the pointer stuff you get around by using arrays in this implementation, the arrays essentially contain long's which are the native pointers.

Comment: CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES would suggest that your second neuron layer (+weights, bias...) is too large to call the kernel. Have you tried this kernel on a minimal network size? Is it possible to free/read the old buffers from global memory before each call?

Comment: The second neuron layer in this case, is only 10 neurons. The input layer was 35 neurons. A previous implementation did read back the contents of the buffers after each call, and set them up again for the next pass, resulting in a cleaner for loop that did not bug.

Also bear in mind that if I used the clFinish() rather than the clWaitForEvents(), the error would instead be CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE at this point.